# C Pointer Assignment in a function

Tags: c, function, pointers, variable-assignment

Why can't I assign a point in a function. As you noticed in the following code. I can not assign pointer p1 pointed to the correct address after the function return. But with the global pointer *p, I can store the address information.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *p = NULL;
void test(int * pt1, int**pt2){
    p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));    
    pt1 = p;
    *pt2 = p;
    printf("p points to %p\n", p);
    printf("pt1 points to %p\n", pt1);
    printf("pt2 points to %p\n", *pt2);
}

int main(void) {
    int *p1 = NULL; 
    int *p2 = NULL;

    printf("p points to %p\n", p);
    printf("p1 points to %p\n", p1);
    printf("p2 points to %p\n", p2);

    test(p1, &p2);

    printf("p points to %p\n", p);
    printf("p1 points to %p\n", p1);
    printf("p2 points to %p\n", p2);

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
p points to (nil)
p1 points to (nil)
p2 points to (nil)
p points to 0x8acb008
pt1 points to 0x8acb008
pt2 points to 0x8acb008
p points to 0x8acb008
p1 points to (nil)
p2 points to 0x8acb008
```

Comment: In C, everything is passed by value. Pointers ain't no exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside `test` the variable `pt1` is a discrete pointer in its own right. That is to say it is *not* merely an alias for `p1`, but rather a copy that exists only for the lifetime of the call.

Thus whatever assignment you make to it is only exits for the duration of that call and is not propagated outside of it. When you return from `test` the pointer `pt1` ceases to exist and any changes aren't copied back.

As well as using an extra "layer" of pointer like you did with `pt2` sometimes it's appropriate to use the return value to "share" changes with a wider audience:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *p = NULL;
int *test(int * pt1, int**pt2){
    p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));    
    pt1 = p;
    *pt2 = p;
    printf("p points to %p\n", p);
    printf("pt1 points to %p\n", pt1);
    printf("pt2 points to %p\n", *pt2);
    return pt1;
}

int main(void) {
    int *p1 = NULL; 
    int *p2 = NULL;

    printf("p points to %p\n", p);
    printf("p1 points to %p\n", p1);
    printf("p2 points to %p\n", p2);

    p1=test(p1, &p2);

    printf("p points to %p\n", p);
    printf("p1 points to %p\n", p1);
    printf("p2 points to %p\n", p2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You arre passing the p1 in by value, so the changes are only visable within the scope of that function. pass in a pointer to that pointer, as you did with p2, and you are fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *p = NULL;
void test(int **pt1, int**pt2){
    p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));    
    *pt1 = p;
    *pt2 = p;
    printf("p points to %p\n", p);
    printf("pt1 points to %p\n", pt1);
    printf("pt2 points to %p\n", *pt2);
}

int main(void) {
    int *p1 = NULL; 
    int *p2 = NULL;

    printf("p points to %p\n", p);
    printf("p1 points to %p\n", p1);
    printf("p2 points to %p\n", p2);

    test(&p1, &p2);

    printf("p points to %p\n", p);
    printf("p1 points to %p\n", p1);
    printf("p2 points to %p\n", p2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `p1` by value, so it's not updated in the `main` function. However, you are passing `p2` by reference (note that you wrote `&p2`), so it can be changed.

Comment: Oops, looks like 75inchpianist beat me to it!